# Ferry connection between Crimea - Kerch and Georgia?

Tags: georgia-country, ferries, ukraine

Does anybody know if the ferry service is bacK? I will need it next spring - 2014.

Comment: When did it cease? I knew one each person who took it in each direction 1.5 or 2 years ago I think.

Comment: http://www.ukrferry.com/schedules/kerch-poti

Answer (score 2):

On the ukferry.com website, it states that "Service is temporarily suspended with effect" for this route.

A email to their Customer Service Line (ukf@ukrferry.com) also left me with a doubt ("We have no status currently of the opening of that route"), that it will be opened anytime soon.

There are plenty of options if you could leave from Ilyichevsk, however, it is at least 8 hours from Kerch by land.